# Android keyboard suggestions - Numbers doesn't appear

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want to enable suggestions for the Android keyboard. Currently I have enabled it through the device.
What and where should I write the code for enabling the same?

And, in the suggestions is there any possibility to add numbers as well? If not suggestions atleast see the numbers that I am typing? I want this because, the text box is covered by the keyboard and I am unable to see the text I am typing. So, is it possible to enable suggestions such that every word I type is made visible in the suggestions window?

As you can see below, the number 1234 has appeared after I typed it on the keyboard. However on the device, this suggestion doesn't appear.

[image: Sreenshot]

The image is supposed to appear right above.

Comment: This doesnt help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578322/auto-suggest-phrase-sentence-completion or this?

Comment: Nope, that is not what I am looking for. I am looking for numbers' suggestions.

Comment: can you please paste some information or other details that can help to understand it better or may be some images?