# Get next word (or POS) suggestion for a given sentence. Autocomplete a sentence

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, opennlp, gate, uima

I have to implement auto-suggestion feature in my desktop based java application. The requirement is as follow:
A user will give a sentence as input and i have to return the next possible `Part-Of-Speech` as suggestion. 
Eg:
1. `UserInput:` Mike wants to  `Suggestions:` [read, play, have fun, study, code, .., etc] 
2. `UserInput:` Mike have  `Suggestions:` [to read, Naboo N-1 starfighter, horse, .., etc]

It's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578322/auto-suggest-phrase-sentence-completion), but this one is for Android. Can this be done by using some NLP libraries like Stanford-NLP or OpenNLP etc? Do let me know, if you require some more detail.

Thanks!

Comment: ummm.. i want this for a desktop based java application not android application

Comment: `Part of Speech` is for example a noun or a verb. That is not what you want. You want a simply markov chain based on n-grams.

Comment: yeah, I have an storage from where i can get the `noun` or  `verb`. ex: List<String> getWords(String POS). So my problem is to guess the next `POS`, given an incomplete sentence. and if this markov-chain based on n-gram can solve my problem, can you please give me some relevant link?